# Am I not allowed to edit my own question?

Tags: discussion

I am trying to edit a question of my own on Stack Overflow. But it doesn't allow me.

It displays something like 'you should edit at least six characters'. Why should I edit all if I just need to edit a word or two?

Comment: Because most of the time, such short edit are not significant, thus, to avoid noise, the limit is set to 6 while your rep is <2k.

Comment: You should always be able to edit your own question. Which is it - your own (as you say in the title), or somebody else's?

Comment: if its your own question you should be able to save the edit changes even if you just added a space in the question. I juz checked. :)

Comment: Most such limitations were intended to limit abuse.  In this case having a new user constantly re-activate his question with a small edit.  The limitation is removed when you are "trusted", having enough rep to know how the system works.

Comment: Editing the question "bumps" it in the list of questions.  The restriction is to prevent people from abusing the edit priv in order to get more eyes on their posts.

Comment: @Pekka Is it okay to edit an old question entirely to make it a completely different one? If the old question doesn't have any answers / comments or any votes, specially when someone is in question ban and they are unable to ask a new question.

Comment: Is it okay to edit an old question entirely to make it a completely different one?

- No.

Answer (score 8):

Like the message you've gotten says:

> *"You should edit at least six characters"*

The edit you want to make is too minor. See if you can improve more about the post, and you'll be able to save the edit.

This character limitation is [removed at 2000 reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit).

Comment: Well, this explains it.  That said, I'm not sure a reputation limitation makes a lot of sense.  There's plenty of times I read read my posts, and the realize I need to modify "it's" to "its".  Sure, my rep allows me to do so; but, it's not really something I'd want to deny to newer users.